# How to connect to remote MongoDB with Authentication and SSH Tunneling

Tags: mongodb, shell, ssh

I am trying to connect to Remote MongoDB using the below credentials from ROBO3T and it is getting connected successfully.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to replicate the same through .sh file i.e, shell script and it is not working.

1) This is the command I am executing frm mongo shell script ,

```
mongo --username username --password password --authenticationDatabase admin --host ip-test --port 27017
```

But I am getting Socket Exception and COnnection Timed Out Exception and not able to connect to Remote MongoDB.

2) So, I have added the below ip in mongo.cfg file,

```
bindIp: ip-test,127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0
```

3) I have also have ip-test defined in windows Host file as well.

4) I have also tried the below command after all configuartions ,

```
mongo -u username -p password ip-test:27017/sample --authenticationDatabase admin
```

But still getting same Socket Error and Connection Timedout.

5) Then I tried giving the ssh Tunneling (configuration) in the mongo shell command itself as below,

```
mongo ip-test:27017/sample -u username -p pasword -e 'SHOW DATABASES;' -h 127.0.0.1 | ssh -fN -l root -i "path for private key/id_rsa" -L 22:ip-test:27017 ip-test
```

This is not giving any Socket Exception, but its giving Connection Timedout.

When i try to connect ssh independently from terminal, its successful.

But the issue is I want to combine mongo shell command with both authentication and ssh tunneling in a single command.

Can anyone help me in understanding, how to get connected to Remote MongoDB server with Authentication and SSH configurations via .SH file(Shell Script)?

I am very much new to ssh Tunneling with shell script, need kind help.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Have you found the issue??? I am facing kind of same issue.
https://www.reddit.com/r/mongodb/comments/dq6kwt/how_to_do_ssh_forwarding_in_compassmongodb_client/